# Inconsistent grid area heights on Chrome vs Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, grid, css-grid

In Chrome I have `#main` (olive color) 300px (it's OK).

But in Firefox I have 1180px. Why? And how to fix it?

Look on https://jsfiddle.net/jocke5a/vrrtyc65/1/

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 20px 120px 50px 20px 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background-color: red;
}

#i-panel {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#s-panel {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background-color: brown;
}

#n-panel {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 7;
  background-color: blue;
}

#set {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background-color: green;
}

#hl-panel {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 4 / 7;
  background-color: orange;
}

#main {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background-color: olive;
}

#komentare {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 5 / 6;
  background-color: gold;
}

#footer {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
  grid-row: 7 / 8;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">
    <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="i-panel">
    <div style="height: 10px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="s-panel">
    <div style="height: 300px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="n-panel">
    <div style="height: 0px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="set">
    <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="hl-panel">
    <div style="height: 3700px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div style="height: 270px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="komentare">
    <div style="height: 1700px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <div style="height: 60px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The height inconsistency includes both `#main` and `#s-panel`.

Here's your code for those elements:

```
#main {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background-color: olive;
}

#s-panel {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 5;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

The problem area appears to be the `grid-row` property

As you noted, in Chrome, `grid-row: 3 / 5` results in a grid area height of 300px for both elements. In Firefox, the grid area height for both is 1180px.

Without going into a deeper investigation, which may take more time than I have right now, I can tell you this: *If you switch both elements to `grid-row: 3 / 4`, then their grid area heights become 300px on both browsers.*

Comment: in nightly v61 is good. I cant switch on #main cause #s-panel going on other position in other resolution.